# Why is my Textfield cursor shows on start position of existing Text when refocus

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-textinputfield

Why does the cursor shows up at the beginning of the existing text, instead of the position where the user taps,  when I re-edit my TextField. This happens when you unfocus the textfield then refocus on it again.

Example code:

```
class Mypage extends StatelessWidget {
  const Mypage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: TextEditingController()..text = 'Existing Text Here',
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                },
                child: Text('Unfocus'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is by default, using a `TextEditingController` without setting the `selection` property, will be at the first character/text value.
You can try something like this:

`String textValue = 'Existing Text Here';`

```
TextField(
  controller: TextEditingController()..value = TextEditingValue(
  text: textValue,
  selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
  TextPosition(offset: textValue.length))
    )
  ),
```

Comment: I've tried this one before, but this is not what I'm looking. What I want is to show the cursor where the user taps, just like the first time you tap  the TextField.

Is there a way to reset the TextEditingController so that it acts like it's the first time you're editing it?